# Can lines that are not parallel or perpendicular to each other fill up $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

As title says, can a union of lines that are not paralell or perpendicular to each other be $\mathbb{R}^3$? The number of lines does not matter. It may be countable or uncountable.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "fill up"?

Comment: union, I am saying. Edited my question.

Comment: It may **not** be countable.

Comment: OK, so what about possibility of union being $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Does 'perpendicular' imply that the lines intersect? Or does it mean perpendicular _after translation_?

Comment: I meant intersect. Sorry for causing confusion.

Comment: Can anyone provide vector calculus reasoning?

Comment: @Euclid: Your original -- perhaps unclear -- question appears to have been adequately answered by (another) Arthur below.  To preserve this answer I have _reverted_ the question back to its previous version.  Feel free to ask your indended question as a new question.  (Incidentally, now by "intersecting" to you mean just intersecting, or _orthogonal_ and intersecting?  Be careful when phrasing your next question.  Cheers!)

Answer (score 4):

There is an injection from the set of points in $\Bbb R^3$ to the set of directions contained in the (open) first octant, for instance, via [space-filling curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve). (Fill the space with a curve, this gives a bijection from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R$. Now inject that real line into the space $\{(\theta, \phi) | 0 < \theta, \phi < \pi/2\}$, consisting of directions for the lines in spherical coordinates.)

No two such directions are orthogonal, and every point gets a line through it with a unique direction, so it turns out you can fill the space with lines neither parallel nor perpendicular.